# How to pause my first MATLAB GUI while the second one is in front

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-app-designer

I want to find a solution that pauses the GUI that I created using App Designer in MATLAB.

I mean exactly like `uigetfile()`, that when you run it you can’t reach the main GUI windows until you close  the `uigetfile()` window.

I need a way to pause my first GUI in the background while my second GUI is in front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `WindowStyle` property of the second figure window to `'modal'`. See [the documentation for this property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html?searchHighlight=figure&s_tid=doc_srchtitle#buiwuyk-1_sep_shared-WindowStyle).